Caching not working with page.tsx in nextjs - Always see fresh record
Following is a file src/app/dashboard/profile/page.tsx inside the nextjs application. It calls an external service to fetch the data. The definition for authenticatedFetch is shown below. It uses a fetch to get the data. I have been reading caching in nextjs. Shouldn't the page refresh always load the same data? Is this not how caching works? But everytime I reload the page and the database has been modified, it returns a new data. Why does that happen? Is this not how caching works in NextJS?
src/app/dashboard/profile/page.tsx:
import { HTTPActions, ServerPaths } from "@/actions/consts";
import UserProfile from "@/components/dashboard/Profile";
import { UserProfileResponse } from "@/server/dto/response.dto";
import { authenticatedFetch } from "@/util/route";
import React from "react";

async function getServerData() {
  const fetchResponse = await authenticatedFetch(
    ServerPaths.PROFILE,
    HTTPActions.GET,
    {}
  );
  const response = (await fetchResponse.json()) as UserProfileResponse;
  return response;
}

export default async function Profile() {
  const profile = await getServerData();
  return (
    <main>
      <UserProfile profile={profile.data} key={"user-profile"} />
    </main>
  );
}

Here is how the authenticatedFetch method looks like.
"use server";

import { headers } from "next/headers";

export const authenticatedFetch = async (
  url: string,
  method: string,
  body: any = null
): Promise<Response> => {
  return FetchAPI.authenticatedFetch(url, method, body);
};

abstract class FetchAPI {
  static async authenticatedFetch(
    url: string,
    method: string,
    body: any = null
  ): Promise<Response> {
    const headersList = headers();
    const requestHeaders = {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Cookie: headersList.get("cookie") || "",
    };

    const options = {
      method: method,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      body: method.toLowerCase() !== "get" ? JSON.stringify(body) : null,
    };

    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.GO_BACKEND}${url}`, options);
    return response;
  }
}


is it https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#dynamic-functions
